# Solve the equation $\tan(x-45 °)+\cot x =2$ for $0°\le x\le180°$

Tags: trigonometry

This is A levels trigonometry I am doing self studying so I have no teacher if someone could help me that would be great.

Comment: First, express $\tan(x - 45^{\circ})$ in terms of $\tan(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions

Comment: “Joshua wang” what do I do next?

Comment: This is mere opinion, naturally, but first, you should say farewell to degrees. Mathematicians use radian, mostly ($\pi/4$ instead of $45°$).Then, learn trigonometric identities, especially addition theorem, or $\cot x = \tan(\pi/2-x)$. Then, you may discover that $\displaystyle\tan\alpha+\tan\beta=\frac{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos\alpha\cos\beta}=\frac{2\sin(\alpha+\beta)}{\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)}$.

Comment: You have the equation $$\dfrac{X-1}{1+X}+\dfrac1X=2\iff X^2+2x-1=0$$ where $X=\tan(x)$.


 From this you have $x=\arctan(-1\pm\sqrt2)$ i.e. $x=22.5º$ and $x=-67.5º$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$\tan(x - 45^{\circ}) + \cot(x) = 2$$

Using $\tan(x + y) = \frac{\tan(x) + \tan(y)}{1 - \tan(x)\tan(y)}$:

$$\frac{\tan(x) + \tan(-45^{\circ})}{1 - \tan(x)\tan(-45^{\circ})} + \cot(x)=2$$

Using $\tan(-45^{\circ}) = -1$ and $\cot(x) = \frac{1}{\tan(x)}$:

$$\frac{\tan(x) - 1}{1+\tan(x)} + \frac{1}{\tan(x)} = 2$$

Cross-multiplying:

$$\tan(x)\big(\tan(x) - 1\big) + \big(1 + \tan(x)\big) = 2\tan(x)\big(1 + \tan(x)\big)$$

Simplifying:

$$\tan^{2}(x) + 2\tan(x) - 1 = 0$$

Using the Quadratic Formula:

$$\tan(x) = \frac{-2\pm\sqrt{2^{2} + 4(1)(1)}}{2}$$

$$\tan(x) = -1 + \sqrt{2}, -1 - \sqrt{2}$$

First, we will solve $\tan(x) = -1 + \sqrt{2}$. Since this doesn't correspond to any of the usual angles, we will see if it is a half-angle. We have:

$$\tan(2x) = \tan(x + x) = \frac{2\tan(x)}{1 - \tan^{2}(x)} = \frac{2\sqrt{2}-2}{1 - (\sqrt{2}-1)^{2}} = \frac{2\sqrt{2}-2}{2\sqrt{2}-2}=1$$

$\tan(y) = 1$ when $y = 225^{\circ}, 45^{\circ}$, so $\tan(2x) = 1$ means $x$ might equal $112.5^{\circ}, 22.5^{\circ}$. Checking these, we find that only $x=22.5^{\circ}$ works.

Now, we solve for when $\tan(x) = -1-\sqrt{2}$:

$$\tan(2x) = \frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^{2}(x)} = \frac{-2-2\sqrt{2}}{1 - (-1-\sqrt{2})^{2}}=\frac{-2-2\sqrt{2}}{-2-2\sqrt{2}}=1$$

Once again, we find that $\tan(2x) = 1$, so $x$ could be $112.5^{\circ}$ or $22.5^{\circ}$. Checking, we find that only $112.5^{\circ}$ works.

Thus, $\boxed{x = 22.5^{\circ}, 112.5^{\circ}.}$

Comment: Thank you very much @Joushua Wang this is very helpful. The only part I don’t get it the cross multiplying how do we get 2 tan if we multiply tan by -1?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: with $t:=\tan x$, the equation is $\frac{t-1}{t+1}+\frac1t=2$, which you can rearrange to a quadratic in $t$.

Comment: It is here I get suck on.

Comment: @Hiran If you edit your question to show what you _did_ manage, I can help with what you _couldn't_ . Is it rearrangement to a quadratic, solving the quadratic, or converting $t$ to $x$?

Comment: thank youuu very much I was able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

As an A Level student myself, I really recommend you get [these textbooks](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Edexcel-level-Mathematics-Textbook-Further/dp/1292183403/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=%23PURE%20MATHEMATICS%20a%20level%20edexcel&qid=1610551982&sr=8-1) if you are doing the Edexcel course; they contain excellent explanation of the course's content as well as hundreds of practice questions.

As for your question:

**HINT**

Use the addition formulae for $\tan$ to give yourself an equation entirely in terms of $\tan x$. If you require any more help please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I have the https://bookis.com/no/books/sue-pemberton-cambridge-international-as-andamp-a-level-mathematics-2018-1?gclid=Cj0KCQiA0fr_BRDaARIsAABw4EvvTlTuPir4p905VhgkI-jZ0h-OBOnvO8pJYrI6b5Zvv7jnYJWoN6UaAjsqEALw_wcB. I don’t know how to get to the angles.